# MySQL group by distinct combination of columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

Say I have the following result set from a MySQL query:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----|------|------
 1   |   2  |
 2   |   1  |
 1   |   3  |
 3   |   1  |
 3   |   1  |
```

How can I group the result set such that it looks like:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----|------|------
  1  |   2  |
  1  |   3  |
```

Comment: ..GROUP BY LEAST(col1,col2),GREATEST(col1,col2)

Comment: I tried GROUP BY (col1, col2), as well as selecting col1 and col2 as DISTINCT columns, but neither worked.

Comment: Mihai's comment worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Mihai's comment to the original question, the solution is:

```
GROUP BY LEAST(col1, col2), GREATEST(col1, col2)
```